# Webpack - Deploying the application to different environments

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, hapi.js

I am approaching a point where I need to have ability to deploy application to different environments (QA, Staging and Production).

Before I did it this way:
- I have three servers (QA, Staging and Production).
- I remote to the server
- On that instance gitbash is installed and pointed to appropriate GIT branch
- I simply pull the code
- Run the application
That worked great for Backbone and Sails project I have done.

Now in this project, I am using React and Hapi, in essence same logic.
What gets me thinking is the webpack. I ended up using webpack, and it seems very powerfull. I would like to use the Webpack for this task.

I have checked online resources and documentation, but I did not find the answer that I understand.

Is it possible to make webpack automatically upload and deploy the code to environments of my choosing?

Shall I continue to use my old way, which is:
- Connect to server
- Pull the code
- Run 'npm run webpack' on the server

Or there is more modern way of doing these things?

Answer (score 0):

The most convenient way to do smth. - is always a single command line on your machine. There are a lot of tools for variety OS. May be somebody make here a list of all possibilities. But I don't think webpack is among them - webpack is just a module builder. Personally, I like `git-deployments` and `webhooks`. It works like this:

We push commits to a branch, e.g. `release`, then github-bitbucket-gitlab notifies our IIS or Azure backend(s) with [Kudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu) installation, about the changes. And the tool automatically pulls the new commits and runs the deployment scripts. And in deployment scripts you would have your `npm run webpack`. That's all.